# lxc-execute gives error

Tags: lxc

I have been stuck on trying to  resolve the errors which I get when I run  a command "`sleep 100`" on a lxc container.

I created a simple container using

```
~$:lxc-create -t download -n guest -- -d ubuntu -r xenial -a amd64
```

However when I try to execute a command on this new container I am getting 
the errors

```
~$lxc-execute -n guest -- sleep 100
```

lxc-execute: utils.c: safe_mount: 1692 Invalid argument - Failed to mount `/sys/kernel/debug onto /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/sys/kernel/debug`

> init.lxc.static: initutils.c: mount_fs: 36 failed to mount /proc :
>   Device or resource busy

Similarly

```
~$: lxc-execute -n guest -- /bin/bash
```

> lxc-execute: utils.c: safe_mount: 1692 Invalid argument - Failed to
>   mount /sys/kernel/debug onto
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/sys/kernel/debug
>
> init.lxc.static: initutils.c: mount_fs: 36 failed to mount /proc :
>   Device or resource busy
>
> bash: cannot set terminal process group (1): Inappropriate ioctl for
>   device
>
> bash: no job control in this shell root@guest:/#

Please can someone advice on what is missing in my configuration.

Thanks
KN